# Meaning of -= and += in Scala Trait definition

Tags: scala, traits

I'm learning Scala from the Book `Scala in Action`, In the chapter were the authors is explaining Traits. The explanation has the following code block, in which I can't figure out the meaning of -= and += in Trait definitionnof `Updatable`

Kindly Help!

```
package com.scalainaction.mongo
import com.mongodb.{DBCollection => MongoDBCollection }
import com.mongodb.DBObject

class DBCollection(override val underlying: MongoDBCollection)
extends ReadOnly
trait ReadOnly {
   val underlying: MongoDBCollection
   def name = underlying getName
   def fullName = underlying getFullName
   def find(doc: DBObject) = underlying find doc
   def findOne(doc: DBObject) = underlying findOne doc
   def findOne = underlying findOne
   def getCount(doc: DBObject) = underlying getCount doc
}
trait Updatable extends ReadOnly {
   def -=(doc: DBObject): Unit = underlying remove doc
   def +=(doc: DBObject): Unit = underlying save doc
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are just names of methods. Names of methods etc. in Scala are not limited to letters, digits and underscores as in other languages like Java. So, names such as `+=` and `-=` are perfectly acceptable names for methods.

Note that in Scala there isn't a difference between methods and operators. Operators are just methods. There are two syntaxes for calling methods that have one parameter: the "normal" syntax using a dot and arguments between parentheses, and the infix syntax.

```
val a = 3
val b = 2

// The infix syntax for calling the + method
val c = a + b

// Normal method call syntax for calling the + method
val d = a.+(b)
```

Note that in your example, infix syntax is being used to call methods on `underlying`. For example: `underlying find doc` is the same as `underlying.find(doc)`.